# Iterate over google map JSON data in laravel

Tags: laravel, api, maps

I am calling a method that calls the google places api and returns JSON data. I need to iterate over the json data. Do i have to use CURL request to call the url or using redirect is fine?

```
public function getPlaces(Request $request) {

        $latitude = $request->latitude;
        $longitude = $request->longitude;
        $radius = $request->radius;
        $service_type = $request->service_type;
        $api_key = env("API_KEY");

        $toSend = Redirect::to("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=$latitude,$longitude&radius=$radius&type=$service_type&key=$api_key");


        $arr = [];
        $data = [];
        $data = json_decode($toSend);

        foreach( $data as $v ) {

            //perform operation
        }   

        return something;

    }
```

Comment: can i see dd($toSend)?

Comment: $data not return array

Comment: @EtibarRustemzade I am developing it as an API so using postman. If I just do it normally on a browser it works fine.

Comment: @EtibarRustemzade I have updated my question and added the route now. Please check

Comment: which domain? :)

Comment: @EtibarRustemzade developing locally

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161579/discussion-between-abhijit-borkakoty-and-etibar-rustemzade).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a redirect. That is attempting to redirect the browser using a HTTP 301

Use a library like [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/overview.html#installation) to make a restful GET request from your server to Google's.

---

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$res = $client->get('put your url here');

if($res->getStatusCode() == 200){

     $toSend = $res->getBody();


}
```

---